# Configuring dynamic subdomain creation with php

Tags: php, subdomain

I changed my host and everything I had on the old one, I replicated to the new one and it does not work. Maybe I am missing something ?!

I have a dedicated server that is using plesk as a control panel.

What I did:

1. In plesk I went to that specific domain and changed the Apache & nginx settings to add the virtual host, like so:

> < VirtualHost *:80>
>
> ServerName example.com
>
> ServerAlias *.example.com
>
> UseCanonicalName Off
>
> < /VirtualHost>

2. I add the *.example.com A record in my domain control panel
3. My htaccess looks like so (although it worked on the last server, so I assume everything is ok)

> < Files .htaccess>
>
> order allow,deny
>
> deny from all
>
> < /Files>
>
> < IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
>
> RewriteRule ^/?edit/([^/.]+)$ ./edit.php?url=$1
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
>
> RewriteRule .* view.php?url=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
>
> < /IfModule>

EDIT: Solution was to add the *.example.com subdomain in Plesk.

Comment: AFAIK - you shouldn't have spaces in the parenthesis

Comment: @treyBake those were just to be able to post here in the quote section as if i did not add a space after the < that line would have been ignored

Comment: I meant the `<VirtualHost>` bits - not the use of `>` before each line

Comment: I can't believe that I missed this... I had to create a *.example.com subdomain in Plesk